# How can I trace the cause of an invalid PC fault on Cortex M3?

Tags: arm

I have an STM32 Cortex M3 that is experiencing an intermittent invalid PC (INVPC) fault. Unfortunately it takes a day or more to manifest and I don't know the cause.

I have the device paused in the debugger after the fault happened. The INVPC flag is set. The stacked registers are as follows:

```
0x08003555 xPSR
0x08006824 PC
0x08006824 LR
0x00000000 R12
0x08003341 R3
0x08006824 R2
0xFFFFFFFD R2
0x0000FFFF R0
```

Unfortunately the return address 0x08006824 is just past the end of the firmware image. The decompilation of that region is as follows:

```
    Region$$Table$$Base
        0x08006804:    08006824    $h..    DCD    134244388
        0x08006808:    20000000    ...     DCD    536870912
        0x0800680c:    000000bc    ....    DCD    188
        0x08006810:    08005b30    0[..    DCD    134241072
        0x08006814:    080068e0    .h..    DCD    134244576
        0x08006818:    200000bc    ...     DCD    536871100
        0x0800681c:    00001a34    4...    DCD    6708
        0x08006820:    08005b40    @[..    DCD    134241088
    Region$$Table$$Limit

** Section #2 'RW_IRAM1' (SHT_PROGBITS) [SHF_ALLOC + SHF_WRITE]
    Size   : 188 bytes (alignment 4)
    Address: 0x20000000
```

I'm not sure this address is valid. The disassembly of that address in the debugger looks like nonsense, maybe data interpreted as code or something.

[image]

Is there any way I can trace this back to see where the exception happened? If necessary I can add some additional code to capture more information.

Comment: This isn't complete enough to be an answer, but might offer a hint.  The fact that `LR` and `PC` are equal pre-fault suggests that the code has attempted to 'return' to this address, via a `BX LR` or an implicit return by popping a stacked `LR` into `PC`.  This in turn suggests corruption of `LR`, probably while it was held on the stack, which in turn suggests stack corruption via a stack overflow, or a stack-local buffer over/underrun, or a weird race.

Comment: Thanks @cooperised, that is my feeling as well. The project uses the RTX RTOS (CMISS implementation) and the fact that it takes a long time to happen does suggest stack overflow or a bad pointer, but it's very hard to track down the particular circumstances that cause it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure how it works on Cortex M3, but on some other ARMs PSR register holds processor mode bits that could help you find out when it happens (in user mode, IRQ, FIQ etc). Each mode generally have it's own stack.

For user mode, if you use some RTOS with multi-tasking, you probably have many stacks for each task, but you could try to find out which task is current one (was running before crash).

When you find crashed task (or IRQ) you could try to look at it's stack for addresses of all routines and find out what was called before accident. Of course if stack was not unrecoverably corrupted.

This is what I'd start investigation from. If you find crashed task or even function but still have no idea what happens, you could make something like small circular history buffer where you write some codes on every step of your program, so you could find what it does last even if stack was destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. I did look at the processor status bits and it isn't in an interrupt, but I don't know if they get cleared when the fault handler is executed.

Comment: Well, then you could try to look at all task's stacks to find if there something strange like stack filled with garbage or some data. If your RTX RTOS is open source you could look at task context structure to find where stack pointers stored and check it. And my last idea was history.